# Refresh page after button was clicked and location changed

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a button which generates a word document by changing the location of the page using javascript to my php script which outputs the file on the same page as the location was changed by using:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .$templateName . '.docx"');
readfile( $tempFileName);
```

Anyways, when I click the button, the php script changes alters a row of data which the page which contains the button harbours. Once the button is clicked, it just generates the word document but does *not* refresh the page and so, the user will think the button had only the effect of generating the word document but not changing the record and only after refreshing the page will the user notice the difference the button made.

My button's HTML is as such:

```
<input type="button" value="Generate Final Demand" onClick="self.location='DOCXGenerateDocument.php?templ=finaldemand&invoiceid=<?=$_GET['id']?>'">
```

Have any ideas on how I can accomplish the task of refreshing the page once the document has came back?

Comment: are the shorttags enabled in your php.ini or do you use php 5.4?

Comment: I use the latest version of PHP & Have shortags enabled.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `setTimeout()` and guess when the page should be back, then do a `document.location.reload(true)` when the timeout triggers.

It ain't pretty, but it should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `self.location`, use `window.location`

e.g. 
`onClick="window.location='DOCXGenerateDocument.php?templ=finaldemand&invoiceid=<?=$_GET['id']?>'"`

Let me know if this works.
 For more reference you can check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) on MDN.

Comment: The page remains unrefreshed and the data was not loaded onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way to do this is to take advantage of session locking in PHP. Let us assume that your DOCX generating script uses session and does not release it until the script ends. Now, if the browser tries to load another PHP script that also uses session, the second script will stall until the first script is done. Make that second script a dynamically-loaded Javascript with simply "location.reload()", then you have what you need.

Function to start the download:

```
function getDoc() {
    self.location='DOCXGenerateDocument.php?templ=finaldemand&invoiceid=<?=$_GET['id']?>';
    setTimeout("var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); s.src = 'read.js.php'; document.body.appendChild(s);", 100);
}
```

The reload script:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
location.reload();
```

Comment: Unfortunately the script does not use sessions so that solution is rendered useless.

Comment: Use flock() then. Pass a randomly generated number to both scripts and have them try to get a lock on the same temporary file.